# How to fit a plane based on a 3D point cloud

Tags: 3d, point-clouds, plane, best-fit

I have a 3D point cloud, I want fit a plane based on these points. And I want to know the normal vector of the fitting plane. Which algorithm is the best? Would you please give me detailed steps？ I plan to write using R, any function I can use?

Answer (score 2):

The equation for a plane in three dimensions is `Ax + By + Cz + D = 0`. Hence, the best fitting plane will be the one where `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` are chosen such that when you plug in the 3-D coordinates into the formula, the result is as close to zero as possible. Said another way, you're looking for the best vector `v` that satisfies the matrix equation `Mv = 0`, where `M` is a matrix representing your data points:

```
     | x1  y1  z1  1 |        |  A  |    Need to solve:
     | x2  y2  z2  1 |        |  B  |       Mv = 0
 M = | x3  y3  z3  1 |    v = |  C  |
     |   .  .  .     |        |  D  |
     | xn  yn  zn  1 |
```

I'm not familiar with R, but a quick google search says that the `lsfit` function [should do what you need](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/lsfit.html). Once you compute the coefficients `A-D`, the vector `(A, B, C)` will be the normal vector and the scalar `D` will be the distance the plane is from the origin.

Comment: You also need to add some extra condition (e.g. A²+B²+C²=1) as obviously A=B=C=D=0 is always an exact solution.